# Steamdeck. Opening bash script in terminal allways creates new profile witch broken command

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

i just wrote my first script, everything worked fine when i had it on the desktop.
Now after i moved it to a micro sd, whenever i try to launch it on Terminal it creates a profile where ther command isnt "/bin/bash" but instead "/run/(location of script)"
when i checked the settings for the profiles and viewed them in a list, the name was blank and made changes wont be saved.
also, giving the script execute premission is reset whenever i reinsert the card. can i fix that too?

The code (in case thats important)

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/deck/.config/wireplumber/bluetooth.lua.d/

rm 61-force-bluez.codec.lua
touch Temp.txt
echo 'bluez_monitor.properties["bluez5.codecs"] = "[ sbc ]"' > Temp.txt
mv Temp.txt 61-force-bluez.codec.lua

systemctl --user restart wireplumber
```

i tried multiple "solutions" already. but all of them show no effect.

Comment: Please do not put "SOLVED" or anything similar in the title. You can mark your own answer as accepted to show that you got a slution.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working on an removeable drive !
The Problem was That the sd-cards driver was "Fat" which has no rights to execute scripts, so it just wouldnt save the exe cute permission.
I formated the sd To "ntsf" and now the scripts work flawlessly.